# Match escaped html in regex c#

Tags: c#, html, regex, string, html-escape-characters

How can I escape html codes in Regex?

I need to find the string

```
&amp;
```

in a string like

```
this is my string &amp; this is another string
```

I can not use HtmlEncode/Decode for this purpose cause i need work with tags. That i want i just find the common string.

I use this, and work for example with "another" or "my" but doesn't work with `"&amp;"`.

```
            Regex regularextest = new Regex("\b&amp;\b", options);
            string RSTest = "char $& morechar";
            string lalala = regularextest.Replace("foo &amp; bar", RSTest);
```

It's very frustrating because google replaces the string with an & or "AND" word.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to use regex as opposed to the normal `.Replace()` on the string?

Comment: In addition, in the MSDN says that & and ; are not special chars for Regex in C#

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454  I know it's not an exact duplicate, but it answers your question.  Parsing escaped html faces the same limitations.

Comment: I don't understand why you say "I can not use HtmlEncode/Decode ... cause i need work with tags" - could you elaborate?

Comment: Because the logic of the code, the regular expression it's so much complicated, i reduce it to do the example and find the solution

Comment: @jwd - Perhaps ***I'm*** the one who misread the question.  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `\b&amp;\b` will not match because `&` and `;` are not word characters.

You could try this :

```
Regex regularextest = new Regex("(?<=^|\s+)&amp;(?=\s+|$)", options);
```

Comment: i never think it... of course... maybe is that. Let me try it! :) Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Leandro I am just a guy :) but thanks anyway. There **way** more experienced people in regexes in SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to identify/convert valid entities (non-unicode), you could use this regex
`(?:&(?:[A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*|\#(?:[0-9]+|x[0-9a-fA-F]+));)`
to identify a possible value to replace, pass it to a callback function that further process the entity you wish to replace. This way it could all be done in a single regex global replace (with callback logic).